# hosting the database file on any cloud service

Tags: java, android

I have an android application, which wants the user to login each time he runs the app. So, the login procedure is simple, using the sqlite dabase file i'm using. I've copied the file in assets folder and doing the necessary modifications. But, the database file is of no use unless it is on the server. I don't have any server so i'm thinkin of keeping the database file on dropbox, google drive etc and then read or update that file as per user commands. The question is how to do that? I was searching the web for it, and found that the only way is downloading the db file modifying it and the uploading it back. Can anyone give me an example??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing that isn't possible unless you have a server.

Because, if you are using dropbox, first you'll have to make your file public in order to download it (Not recommended at all. Compromises security). Then you can use the url to download the file. But you won't be able to upload it back (Unless you are able to login to dropbox through your Android code).

Instead if you a web server with `MySQL` n `PHP`, you can easily send `POST` requests to your server.

Comment: that depends. if your free server provides you php and mysql support, that would suffice. Without php and mysql support, you are totally handicapped!

Comment: www.serversfree.com 

it has php and mysql support but looks like, it does the things on the localhost? So, i don't think it'll be global?

Comment: you need to have an accessible url like http://www.serversfree.com/your-folder/your-file.php then you can use this url to run your code. Pass the parameters as `POST` variables.

Comment: So it is possible on that?

Comment: thank you :) 
I'll post back if i have further queries!